# Ubuntu 16.04 suspends every 10 minutes (approximatelly)

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

I have problem that my Ubuntu 16.04 64bit suspends every 10 minutes approximatelly.

I ran `udevadm monitor` before suspend to log it, but I can't figure out what is happening. (I'm not pro in this)

```
root@juldou-asus:~# udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[41298.796467] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.796630] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.796715] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::3c4852d6-d47b-4f46-b05e-b5edc1aa440e:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.796795] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::8c2f4425-77d6-4755-aca3-891fdbc66a58:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.796869] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::3c4852d6-d47b-4f46-b05e-b5edc1aa430a:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.796950] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::f908627d-13bf-4a04-b91f-a64e9245323d:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.797026] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::f908627d-13bf-4a04-b91f-a64e9245323d:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.797108] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::3c4852d6-d47b-4f46-b05e-b5edc1aa440e:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.797177] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::8c2f4425-77d6-4755-aca3-891fdbc66a58:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.797253] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::55213584-9a29-4916-badf-0fb7ed682aeb:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.797321] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::309dcde8-ccb1-4062-8f78-600115a34327:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.797377] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797444] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::55213584-9a29-4916-badf-0fb7ed682aeb:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.797496] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797556] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::fa8f55e8-ab22-42dd-b916-7dce39002574:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.797606] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck5 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797648] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.797695] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797737] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.797785] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck7 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797826] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797862] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck4 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797900] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck5 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797934] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck6 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.797968] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck7 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.798003] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.798035] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck2 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.798066] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.798098] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck4 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.798133] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck5 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.798168] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck6 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.798204] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck7 (machinecheck)
KERNEL[41298.798268] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.798334] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::3c4852d6-d47b-4f46-b05e-b5edc1aa440e:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.798412] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::fa8f55e8-ab22-42dd-b916-7dce39002574:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.798485] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::3c4852d6-d47b-4f46-b05e-b5edc1aa430a:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.798564] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::3c4852d6-d47b-4f46-b05e-b5edc1aa440e:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.798636] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::f908627d-13bf-4a04-b91f-a64e9245323d:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.798698] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::8c2f4425-77d6-4755-aca3-891fdbc66a58:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.798761] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::309dcde8-ccb1-4062-8f78-600115a34327:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.798826] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::55213584-9a29-4916-badf-0fb7ed682aeb:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.798883] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::fa8f55e8-ab22-42dd-b916-7dce39002574:01 (mei)
KERNEL[41298.798940] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill37 (rfkill)
KERNEL[41298.798991] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[41298.799071] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[41298.799156] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[41298.799254] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 (usb)
UDEV  [41298.799339] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.799559] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.800549] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck6 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.801983] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::f908627d-13bf-4a04-b91f-a64e9245323d:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.802909] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::309dcde8-ccb1-4062-8f78-600115a34327:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.803979] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck3 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.804958] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck1 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.805112] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck6 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.805887] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck5 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.807219] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck7 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.808484] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::309dcde8-ccb1-4062-8f78-600115a34327:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.808637] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::55213584-9a29-4916-badf-0fb7ed682aeb:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.809189] remove   /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck4 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.810944] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::8c2f4425-77d6-4755-aca3-891fdbc66a58:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.811725] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::3c4852d6-d47b-4f46-b05e-b5edc1aa430a:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.812947] add      /devices/system/machinecheck/machinecheck4 (machinecheck)
UDEV  [41298.813404] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::fa8f55e8-ab22-42dd-b916-7dce39002574:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.815035] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/mei::3c4852d6-d47b-4f46-b05e-b5edc1aa430a:01 (mei)
UDEV  [41298.815648] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill37 (rfkill)
UDEV  [41298.816180] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [41298.818524] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [41298.823676] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [41298.843637] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 (usb)
KERNEL[41299.054336] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 (usb)
KERNEL[41299.055146] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[41299.097023] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[41299.097455] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[41299.097593] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[41299.098263] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 (usb)
KERNEL[41347.086806] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 (usb)
KERNEL[41347.087653] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[41347.087904] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
KERNEL[41347.087970] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill38 (rfkill)
KERNEL[41347.088290] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.104187] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.106199] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.106328] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.107027] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.107521] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.112637] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.118322] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.119632] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [41347.119675] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [41367.520874] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [41367.522917] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill38 (rfkill)
```